# Why is my SQLite database bloated to 12MB (from 280KB) with single quotes?

Tags: database, sqlite, quote, sqlitemanager

I'm using SQLiteManager. I had a 280KB database that bloated to over 12MB in just one day. I wasn't doing anything atypical. I still only have about 4-6 light results in the entire database.

When I open up the database file with a text editor, I see pages upon pages of single quotes (').

Also, SQLiteManager injects dozens of single quotes directly into the TinyText attributes that I have every now and then. This is visible on SQLiteManager's Web UI.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Could it be that `a` is somehow written back as `'a'`? (So later on it'd be `''a''`, `'''a'''`, etc...)

Comment: You're very probably right. I was thinking something similar. But, what's strange is that the amount of single quotes inside my actual rows don't equate to the 12MB worth that's in the database. Must be a problem with SQLiteManager I'd imagine... Will switch to another SQLite web-based management tool. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever SQLiteManager is doing, can you have it run VACUUM? If that frees the space, you can then have it run periodically; see this link for more information:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

Also, you can set auto_vacuum to FULL:

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum